# How can I handle needing 2 versions of the same dependency in Java w/ Pentaho?

Tags: java, kettle, build-dependencies

I am in a bit of a jam.

I am working on upgrading our software to have Kettle 6.1. Specifically, we need the feature of S3FileOutput. Meanwhile, our application was already using the aws-sdk for other things.

So I am running into a problem: Pentaho Kettle requires version 1.0.something of aws-sdk. Our application, on the otherhand needs 1.9.6 of the aws-sdk.

To give more details, the feature of Kettle we require is in the pentaho-big-data-legacy plugin. Even if I upgrade to the latest version of Kettle, pentaho-big-data-legacy still uses the old version of the aws-sdk.

I've read a bit about plugins having special classloaders, so one option I was considering is that maybe I am not downloading the right dependency. However, when I tried downloading pentaho-big-data-plugin instead of pentaho-big-data-legacy, I got weird errors, so I stopped going down this path.

I was wondering if there is any way I could put the Kettle Libs in one folder, and my application libs in another folder, and then set some sort of a PENTAHO environment variable to pick up the libraries from the alternative folder.

Another option is if I could somehow set the pentaho classloader, but I don't know if this is possible.

What are my options for having 2 versions of the aws-sdk in my application, with regards to Kettle?

Comment: Do you use Maven or Gradle to build? If so, there are plugins designed to help with this situation.

Comment: I use Maven. I'm not familiar with the tools you are describing. To be clear, I'm not having a problem downloading them. I am having a problem running my code. I only have a single lib folder for all my dependencies right now. I'd have to find some way to have Pentaho load different classes from the main application. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Maven can do much more than download dependencies.

The [Maven Shade](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) plugin can help with your current predicament. During a build, it can rename packages.

You would make a project that builds a "fat jar" (or "uber jar") with Pentaho Kettle and its version of the aws-sdk re-packaged as appropriate. That dependency would be handled before your project is built, so you are free to use whatever version of aws-sdk you like since there is no longer a conflict on package names.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I ended up using "Jar Jar Links", as we use an Ant / Maven combination. It appears that I've done everything correctly, but it is really difficult to tell, as I am still having my original problem (maybe it isn't dependency related. I'm not getting a stack trace, so it is difficult to tell). Can you explain a little more about how the "uber-jar" actually works? Does Jar Jar Links modify the byte code of the dependent classes to refer to the renamed package?

Comment: I don't really know anything about "Jar Jar Links". It is [open source](https://github.com/shevek/jarjar), though. It looks like it changes the class files, but there shouldn't be any fiddling with byte code at runtime.

Comment: I changed my answer a little, by the way. I believe I was mistaken in thinking there would need to be an intermediate step when using the Shade plugin.